# Webhosts that charge monthly?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

I can't seem to find any webhosts that offer hosting on a monthly basis, it seems most of them expect you to pay for a while year ahead of time.  I am ok with "unlimited" bandwidth/data hosts, as my website won't be very demanding.

If anyone can offer some suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you Googled month to month web hosting?

GoDaddy has plans which you pay once per month